# Instagram API how many images can I download at once?

Tags: python, api, instagram

I need to build an app which will download hundreds of images, or get the URL of hundreds of images in each request. Based on search by hashtags.

My problem is, there's no info on what the limit is for images on the Instagram developer site. Any other info I could find is at least 3 years old. I could test it and see for myself, but this wonderful API needs to be in production mode before I can test it.

Does anyone know what the current limit is?

Also if you know of a third party API which can bypass the limit, please let me know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instagram API Documentation for [Rate Limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/):

All rate limits on the Instagram Platform are controlled separately for **each access token and on a sliding 1-hour window.** Live apps have higher rate limits than apps in Sandbox Mode.

> Does anyone know what the current limit is?

The rate limit is **500/hour** if you're using `Sandbox` and **5000/hour** if you go `Live`.

**From documentation:**

Global rate limits are applied **inclusive of all API calls** made by an app per access token over the 1-hour sliding window, **regardless of the particular endpoint.** Rate limits also apply to invalid or malformed requests.

You can check how many request calls are remaining by checking API response header:

> **Note:** AFAIK, This method works only for GET requests; POST requests do not return accurate `x-ratelimit-remaining` values.

```
# It's inexplicably omitted from the current documentation.
x-ratelimit-limit:5000
x-ratelimit-remaining:4898
```

I hope this will help you.